# How can I connect to metamask in pyscript?

Tags: metamask, python, walletconnect

I try to write code to connect to metamask in pyscript I get this error: Error: 'args.method' must be a non-empty string.

```
<button id="connect" >Connect</button> 
<py-script>
  from js import alert, window,console,document
  import asyncio
  from pyodide import create_proxy
  if not window.ethereum: 
    alert("install metamask")
  if window.ethereum:
    button = document.querySelector("button")
    async def request_eth(event):   
      try:
        await window.ethereum.request({"method":"eth_requestAccounts"})
      except Exception as e:   
        console.log(e)
    function=create_proxy(request_eth)
    button.addEventListener("click", function,False)   
</py-script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error I understood that the way how I am passing arg was wrong. here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <button id="connect" style="color:blue" >Connect</button> 
    <py-script>
      from js import alert, window,console,document
      # since sending request to metamask async we need this
      import asyncio
      from pyodide import create_proxy
      if not window.ethereum: 
        alert("install metamask")
      if window.ethereum:
        button = document.querySelector("button")
        # you need to pass event even though you do not use it. Otherwise it will throw this error
        # TypeError: request_eth() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
        async def request_eth(event):   
          try:
            await window.ethereum.request(method="eth_requestAccounts")
          except Exception as e:
            console.log(e)
        function=create_proxy(request_eth)
        button.addEventListener("click", function,False)   
    </py-script>
  </body>
</html>
```